# Do something when Chosen.js select opens/becomes active?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the [Harvest Chosen plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on some multi-selects, but can't figure out the right syntax to do something when the chosen dropdown opens/becomes active.

I know I can use .on() to fire events when an item within the menu is selected, but I'm only interested in firing an event when the menu itself has opened.

```
$('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
```

The [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) provides a trigger option for when the dropdowns are open, but I'm not sure how to actually use it, or if it's actually what I'm looking for to begin with:

```
chosen:showing_dropdown
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From their documentation, it looks like you would have to use

```
$('.chosen-select').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function (evt, params) {
```

instead of change.